# Determining surjectivity

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, functions

So, I've been researching on the method to determine whether a function with a given domain and codomain is surjective or not. The method I always see is taking any number $y$ from the codomain and solving the function for $y$, which gives you the value of $x$ from the domain depending on $y$ which you then feed back into your function and see if that gives you back $y$.

But wouldn't that method just make any function with the domain of $\mathbb{R}$ a surjection?

Say you've got a function you intuitively know is surjective, like $f(x)=2x$, $f:$ $\mathbb{R}$$ ->  < 0, +\infty>$

Applying that methodology to the function, you would first write:

$y=2x$ => $\frac{y}{2} = x$

And then feed that $x$ back into the function to get:

$f(\frac{y}{2})=y$

And now it would go:

$f(x)=f(\frac{y}{2})=2\frac{y}{2}=y$

And this is then supposed to mean that the function $f(x)=2x$ is surjective, even though it isn't because it skips every odd number of the codomain $<0, +\infty>$

So what am I missing here? I've been trying to understand this, but it's just been confusing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple issues.  The first is that you have written $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow[0,\infty]$, but this isn't the case.  See that $f(-1)=-2\not\in[0,\infty]$.  I'll instead assume that the codomain of $f$ is $\mathbb{R}$.

Second, if the domain of $f$ is taken to be $\mathbb{R}$, then it does *not* skip over every odd number - and indeed $f$ is surjective.  For example, $1.5$ is in the domain of the function so we can write $f(1.5)=3$, so $3$ is in the range of $f$.  Similarly  $f((2n-1)/2)=2n-1$ for every integer $n$.

If the domain and of $f$ is taken to be $\mathbb{Z}$, then it *is* true that $f$ skips every odd number.  If the codomain of $f$ is $\mathbb{R}$, then $f$ is *not* surjective since $y/2$ need not be an integer (e.g. when $y=\sqrt{2}$).  If the codomain of $f$ is $\mathbb{Z}$, then still $f$ need *not* be surjective, in particular $f$ misses all the odds as you state.

Comment: Yes there are, and I'm sorry about that. It was very late and I was frustrated. That codomain is from another function, namely $2e^x$. I suppose going by that logic that function is surjective.

But my question still stands. Wouldn't that methodology essentially mean that every $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is surjective by default?

Comment: No, because sometimes you won't find a solution for $x$.  For example, take $f(x)=x^2$.  Then try to solve with $y=-1$.  You have $-1=x^2$ which has no real solutions for $x$.

Comment: So that would mean that $f(x)=x^2$ is surjective for $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{N}$ and isn't surjective for $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ ?

Comment: Almost.  Note that $f(1/3)=1/9$ isn't in $\mathbb{N}$, so $\mathbb{N}$ isn't a possible codomain of $f$.

Comment: Yes, I realized that and was editing my comment as you replied. It's surjective for $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow<0, \infty>$